# Probability: Joint PMFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The probability that a particular student passes a test is 0.75. The number of tests required until the student receives a passing score is thus distributed geometrically, so if $X$ is the number of tests required until passing, then $X \sim \text{Geometric}(0.75)$.

Suppose (for some reason...) that the student is randomly assigned to take the exam in either room A or room B and that this assignment cannot be changed (i.e. the student must take all the tests in the assigned room). The probability that the student passes the exam in room A is  0.75 and the probability that the student passes the exam in room B is 0.85.

**Question: What is the probability that the student passes the test?**

I started by letting $Y$ follow the Bernoulli distribution with $Y \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ assuming that the room assignment is random. But I'm confused what the 0.75 and 0.85 represent. Are those conditional probabilities? If so, how does that help? We know
$$
p_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_{Y}(y)}
$$

so the probability that the student passes on the first try given that he is assigned room A would be 0.75? And if $y=0$ represents room A and $y=1$ represents room B, we of course have $p_{Y}(0) = p_{Y}(1) = 0.5$. I'm not really sure how to proceed from here though since it's unclear what exactly I should be solving for....

edit: forgot to mention that I defined $X$ as a geometric distribution since one of the earlier questions asks what the distribution of number of tests required to pass is. I'm assuming that's needed for this question too...Also, the question of "what is the probability that the student passes the test?" is exactly as is on my assignment, it's not just me being vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If X is geometric, then the student is guaranteed to pass the test in either case, because we have defined the problem to be that he takes tests until he passes. However, we can ask two non-trivial questions:

1. What is the probability he will pass the first test?
2. What is the expected number of tests he will need to take?

For the first question, we want the unconditional probability of passing a test, P(S), given the two conditional probabilities P(S|A) and P(S|B) and unconditional probability P(A)=P(B)=.5. I this case, you can use the law of total probability to get P(S) = P(A)P(S|
A) + P(B)P(S|B).

For the second case, you just need to switch from conditional probability to conditional expectation: E(S) = P(A)E(S|A) + P(B)E(S|B), where the two conditional expectations are just the the expected value of X for each room.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So the probability of passing the first test is simply 0.80 by the law of total probability?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused how to calculate $E(S|A)$ and such. I know the expectation of S alone would just be 4/3 since it is geometric distributed. But in computing $E(S|A)$ don't we need to sum over all values of $s$?

Comment: For first comment: Yes: .5*.75+.5*.85 = .8. E(S|A) is the expected value of the geometric dist. under the assumption that p=.75, while E(S|B) is the same calculation with p=.85.